# PHP socket programming socket_read + socket_write()

Tags: php, sockets

I have a PHP socket application which **connects to a  server**  and sends some data,

i need to extend this script to **send (write)** and **listen** back for a replay from the server

i was trying using  `socket_read()` after `socket_write()`

but it **hangs** the script.

any idea on this ?

Comment: Isn't that the expected state? it should block until data is received.

Comment: actually im sending the message from the server

Comment: You can find some PHP socket code here: [Writing Socket Servers in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1086)

Comment: Ensure that the socket you open is full-duplex an actually open to read data, not only to send data. You should show more code so that could actually be seen.

Comment: What is `$file_bits`? Assuming it's valid, that code will wait until timeout to read from the socket at least one byte.

Comment: @hakre writing working fine  with out `$recv = socket_read ($socket, 1, PHP_BINARY_READ);`

Comment: add a `sleep(1)` after the write, then start reading. Check the return value of the write operation as well. Does return the number of bytes written, FALSE on error.

Comment: lol ! thanks i jot the error my server was returning a empty string ..  now fine .. thanks for help guys !

Comment: @Sudantha: Did so. And always check return values if something is not working ;) It helps ^ ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a workaround add a `sleep(1)` after the write, then start reading.

**Check the return value of the write operation as well first**. Does return the number of bytes written, FALSE on error.

Comment: Please don't add `sleep(1)`

Answer (score 3):

`socket_read()` is blocking. It hangs until there's something to read. Also, you will need to call it repeatedly until it returns an empty string (concatenating what you got so far), and only then will you give the full reply.

This is how socket operations work:

```
socket_write($socket, 'request');
$response = '';
do {
    $buffer = socket_read($socket, $number_of_bytes_to_read);
    $response .= $buffer;
} while (!empty($buffer));
```

Comment: actually im sending the message from the server its not reading by `socket_read(`

Comment: @Sudantha, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that.